Setting QGIS one-to-many relations strength to "Composition" with the "Discover Relations" feature
How do I get QGIS to automatically detect the relationship strength in the "Discover Relations" feature mentioned in QGIS documentation cpt. 16.4.2.1 One to many (1-N) relations (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/de/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/joins_relations.html#one-to-many-1-n-relations)? I'm allways getting relations of strength "Association":

I have defined my foreign key constraint like this:


Shouldn't the ON DELETE CASCADE action result in a "Composition" strength in QGIS? I have defined all my foreign keys accordingly, but QGIS always returns the relationship strength "Association".
The documentation doesn't say anything about it at this point (cp. above). My current workaround is to change the relationship strength in the project file using a text editor, as you can no longer edit once defined relations afterwards via QGIS gui:

Have I configured something incorrectly or does QGIS not provide this function at all?
